# Display Windows File Copy Dialog when copying from a Memorystream?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, winapi

My application will be writing files to the disk from a MemoryStream. Instead of creating my own progress dialogs, I would love to use existing windows functionality e.g. SHFileOperation Win32 API that shows the standard file copy dialog box with animation and progress bar. However, this particular API requires that a path to the source file be specified. Is it possible to somehow use a MemoryStream with this API or is there another API that I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Shell Progress Dialogs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775248(v=vs.85).aspx) for this; this API exposes the dialog only, allowing you to use it to show the progress of any type of operation in your own application.

I wrote a managed wrapper for this a while ago, which you may find useful: [Using Shell Progress Dialogs in Windows Forms Applications](http://www.brad-smith.info/blog/archives/523)

Comment: Perfect...Just what I wanted! Btw, is it ok to use your code in a commercial application?

Comment: No problem, as long as the terms of the license are satisfied (see the copyright section on my website).